# Creating an list of arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays

the program gets the frequency of 0's and 1's in every feature vector(Column) and store it into the array. but then when I access my list of arrays(observed e.g observed.get(0)[0] ) it returns all the 0's in my matrix.

```
DoubleMatrix[] featurevec = new DoubleMatrix[tempfeatures.numCols()];
for (int i = 0; i< featurevec.length; i++) {
    featurevec[i] = tempfeatures.extractVector(false,i);
}

double[]f = new double[2];
ArrayList<double[]> observed = new ArrayList<>();
for (int j = 0; j< featurevec.length; j++) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i< featurevec[j].getNumElements(); i++) 
    {
        if (featurevec[j].get(i) == 1) 
            f[0]++;
        else
            f[1]++;
    }
    observed.add(f);
}
```

Comment: `List<List<Double>>` is what you are looking for, avoid using raw arrays if at all possible.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson That's not helpful. There's nothing wrong with `List<double[]>`.

Comment: explain us in briefly!!

Comment: Why are you incrementing f[0] when you see a 1? Seems backwards to switch them, and could lead to confusion later.

Comment: How can the question be "unclear" when 3 people were able to quickly answer it? The closure reason is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never reset f[].  You are always incrementing the same array, you need to create a new one at each pass.

```
ArrayList<double[]> observed = new ArrayList<>();
for (int j = 0; j< featurevec.length; j++) {
    double[] f = new double[2]; //move this here
    for (int i = 0; i< featurevec[j].getNumElements(); i++) {
        if (featurevec[j].get(i) == 0) //I recommend changing this
            f[0]++;
        else
            f[1]++;
    }
    observed.add(f);
}
```

Also note I changed `if (featurevec[j].get(i) == 1)` to `if (featurevec[j].get(i) == 0)` so the 0 count is stored in f[0] and the 1 count is stored in f[1]. I think this is clearer, and will be easier to manage.

This depends on what `DoubleMatrix` is, not sure since you didn't show us.  You could possibly eliminate your if/else statement by doing something like this since you know you only have 0s and 1:

```
ArrayList<int[]> observed = new ArrayList<int[]>();
for (int j = 0; j< featurevec.length; j++) {
    int[] f = new int[2];
    totalOnes = arraySum(featurevec[j]);
    //total elements - total one count = total zero count
    f[0] = featurevec[j].getNumElements() - totalOnes; 
    f[1] = totalOnes;
    observed.add(f);
}

//not sure of arr's type, unclear from your code, probably Integer?
private int arraySum(ArrayList<T> arr) { 
    int sum = 0;
    //this loop syntax might not work depending on DoubleMatrix's implementation 
    for(int i : arr) 
        sum+=i;
    return sum;
}
```

Although this solution is still O(n^2), perhaps it is a bit clearer.

I'm also not really sure why you are making f[] a double[], since you are only getting the count of 0s and 1s. I changed that too.

Answer (score 0):

I already figure out: I just have to initialized my list like this:

```
    DoubleMatrix[] featurevec = new DoubleMatrix[tempfeatures.numCols()];
    for (int i = 0; i< featurevec.length; i++) {
        featurevec[i] = tempfeatures.extractVector(false,i);
    }
    double[]f = new double[2];
    ArrayList<double[]> observed = new ArrayList<>(tempfeatures.numCols());
    for (int i = 0; i< featurevec.length; i++)
    observed.add(new double[2]);

    for (int j = 0; j< featurevec.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i< featurevec[j].getNumElements(); i++) {
             if (featurevec[j].get(i) == 1) {
                 observed.get(j)[0]++;
             // f[0]++;
            }
            else
                 observed.get(j)[1]++;
               //  f[1]++;
        //observed.add(f);
        }

    }
```

But it has a low performance. because I have 1461* 18584 row column matrix. can somebody suggest to me a better approach in this?

Comment: See my answer which is less modification from your original code.  Unfortunately if you are reading a matrix in, I don't think you can get better performance than O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create only one array and repeated modify it and add it again to your list.

You need to move

```
double[]f = new double[2];
```

inside the loop.

```
DoubleMatrix[] featurevec = new DoubleMatrix[tempfeatures.numCols()];
for (int i = 0; i< featurevec.length; i++) {
    featurevec[i] = tempfeatures.extractVector(false,i);
}

ArrayList<double[]> observed = new ArrayList<>();
for (int j = 0; j< featurevec.length; j++) 
{
    double[]f = new double[2];
    for (int i = 0; i< featurevec[j].getNumElements(); i++) 
    {
        if (featurevec[j].get(i) == 1) 
            f[0]++;
        else
            f[1]++;
    }
    observed.add(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `observed.add(f)` it is adding the same array to the observed list again. In the end you have an ArrayList containing `featurevec.length` references to the same array. You need to create the array `f` inside the loop, so you get a fresh one each time:

```
for (int j = 0; j < featurevec.length; j++) {
    double[] f = new double[2];
    ...
    observed.add(f);
}
```